# var/locks missing in Magento 1.9.2.1

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore

Scratching my head with this. Magento multi store installation, run reindexing from admin OR SSH and although checking the status of `indexer.php` shows 'processing' there is no `var/locks/` folder created?

What might cause this?

Comment: try setting permissions on the var folder to -R 755

Comment: Folder permissions are correct and already set to 755.  I tried 777 also, but still not creating.

Comment: So I cannot find a solution for this.  IF I run from SSH or via Magento Admin var/locks doesn't appear in my magento root /var folder!  This causes problems when one of the processes get stuck for some reason!

Comment: Is the owner of the folders set correctly (chown) ? Are your cron jobs working (can use https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html)?

Comment: yes owners are all correct.  I also find that all of a sudden the search is malfunctioning.  Client has a handful of products with 2 digit SKU, but anything less than 4 digit SKU's aren't showing in search.  They show in back end but not in front.  I have checked all settings are correct to show and made changes to allow 2 digit in search but still nothing!  Wonder if this is linked!